# How concatenating selective query results as string in Neo4j?

Tags: text, neo4j, cypher

### Initial situation

I’ve written a working Cypher query, which returns four distinct quantities.

```
MATCH
  <complex satement>
WITH
  count(DISTINCT typeA) AS amountA,
  count(DISTINCT typeB) AS amountB,
  count(DISTINCT typeC) AS amountC,
  count(DISTINCT typeD) AS amountD
RETURN
  amountA, amountB, amountC, amountD;
```

### Target solution

Instead of a four-column table I want to return a single text string now, where all four quantities are concatenated including a descriptive label. However the quantity must only be part of the string, if its amount is greater than zero.

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"formattedQuantities"                               │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"amountA: 123456, amountC: 9876543, amountD: 2018"  │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

(Because the value of amountB is 0, it is omitted in the result.)

I use this Cyper query for several millions of rows. Because of a performance impact apprehension I don’t want to create and call a custom plugin.

So, how can I return the quantities as string with Cypher and Neo4j? Can you please give me an advice how to solve this challenge? Many thanks in advance for pointing me into the right direction!

---

### approach to the problem / preliminary result

Cypher statement:

```
MATCH
<complex satement>
WITH
  count(DISTINCT typeA) AS amountA,
  count(DISTINCT typeB) AS amountB,
  count(DISTINCT typeC) AS amountC,
  count(DISTINCT typeD) AS amountD
WITH
  ['amountA: ', amountA, ', amountB: ', amountB, ', amountC: ', amountC, ', amountD: ', amountD] AS quantities
RETURN
  reduce(result = toString(head(quantities)), n IN tail(quantities) | result + n) AS formattedQuantities;
```

Result:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"formattedQuantities"                                            │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"amountA: 123456: 1, amountB: 0, amountC: 9876543, amountD: 2018"│
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Still open:

- filtering of amountB because of value 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [FILTER](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-filter) function

```
MATCH
<complex satement>
WITH
  count(DISTINCT typeA) AS amountA,
  count(DISTINCT typeB) AS amountB,
  count(DISTINCT typeC) AS amountC,
  count(DISTINCT typeD) AS amountD
// Reformat to list
WITH
  [{name:'amountA', value:amountA}, {name:'amountB', value:amountB}, {name:'amountC', value:amountC}, {name:'amountD', value:amountD}] AS quantities
// Filter out 0's
WITH filter(x IN quantities WHERE x.value > 0) AS quantities
// Convert list to string
RETURN
  reduce(result = quantities[0].name + ": " + quantities[0].value, n IN tail(quantities) | result + ", " + n.name + ": " + n.value) AS formattedQuantities; AS formattedQuantities;
```

Note that this returns null if all values are 0 (null + string = null)